# Need help in nested if in php

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

I,i have this array which define each number it's color

```
$zero =  array(0=>"Empty",1=>"Red");
$red =   array(3=>"Red",5=>"Red",7=>"Red",9=>"Red",12=>"Red",14=>"Red",16=>"Red",21=>"Red",23=>"Red",25=>"Red",27=>"Red",30=>"Red",32=>"Red",34=>"Red",36=>"Red");
$black = array(2=>"Black",4=>"Black",6=>"Black",8=>"Black",10=>"Black",11=>"Black",13=>"Black",15=>"Black",17=>"Black",22=>"Black",24=>"Black",29=>"Black",31=>"Black",33=>"Black",35=>"Black");

$spin_numbers =array_merge($zero,$red,$black);
```

and I have form,which ask for number to bet,and it's start choosing random number between 0 and 36

```
if (isset($_POST['odd']))
{
  $random_number = mt_rand(0,36);
  if ($random_number == 1 OR $random_number == 3 OR $random_number == 5 OR $random_number == 7 OR $random_number == 9 OR $random_number == 11 OR $random_number == 13 OR $random_number == 15 OR $random_number == 17 OR $random_number == 19 OR $random_number == 21)
  {
    echo $random_number." ".$roulette_numbers[$random_number]." Occured,you won!";
  }
  else if ($random_number == 23 OR $random_number == 25 OR $random_number == 27 OR $random_number == 29 OR $random_number == 31 OR $random_number == 33 OR $random_number == 35)
  {
    echo $random_number." ".$roulette_numbers[$random_number]." Occured,you won!";
  }

  else if($random_number == 2 OR $random_number == 4 OR $random_number == 6 OR $random_number == 8 OR $random_number == 10 OR $random_number == 12 OR $random_number == 14 OR $random_number == 16 OR $random_number == 18 OR $random_number == 20 OR $random_number == 22)
    {
      "Sorry,".$random_number."Occured,your stake goes to Roulette";
    }
    else if ($random_number == 24 OR $random_number == 26 OR $random_number == 28 OR $random_number == 30 OR $random_number == 32 OR $random_number == 34 OR $random_number == 36)
    {
      "Sorry,".$random_number."Occured,your stake goes to Roulette";
    }

}
```

I want Odd numbers which most of them is Red,echo Win Message,and the rest numbers which is Even,echo loose Message,but it's only echo win Message,why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looks like you forgot the echo statement for the 2 even lines.

**echo** "Sorry,".$random_number."Occured,your stake goes to Roulette";

When you are developing you want to set your php.ini to show error and show all, including Notices.

You would have gotten an Notice:
****Notice**:  Undefined variable: roulette_numbers in **[...][...]** on line **19****

Here is a good reference: [How do I get PHP errors to display?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)

Comment: what a fool i am,how did i missed that,im really mixed up and tired that's why,anyway thank you...

Answer (score 1):

Use echo with message.

`echo "Sorry,".$random_number."Occured,your stake goes to Roulette";
 echo "Sorry,".$random_number."Occured,your stake goes to Roulette";`

Comment: i tried this before,not worked,i want also to echo it's color not only the random number

Comment: sorry,i thought i'm using echo,really sorry bro,your answer was also the solution,i dont know why i didn't realize...

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working I was check it in browser.
In your code you just need to echo message which is missed in your code.
Your code is working use echo for displaying message.

Comment: I think this is helpfull for you.